# Element click handler is unset by a mysterious function

Tags: javascript, event-handling, dom-events

I have that bug where the click handler of an element is unset shortly after it's set in the code. How can I know what triggered the unset event?

Answer (score 0):

How the function is unset I dont know, but I always use the following workaround within my code:

```
   function set_handlers(){
    $("#home" ).on("click", function(){
       //some code
    });

    $("#info" ).on("click", function(){
        //more code
    })
}

$("document").ready(function(){
    set_handlers()
});
```

This works and the click handlers wont be removed unless you unbind them